# Problema instalando Android Studio en lubuntu de 32 bits

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu

Instalé la versión ligera de ubuntu de 32 bits, lubuntu en un portatil viejo. Estoy tratando de instalar Android Studio y recibo el error:

"Unable to run mksdcard SDK tool.
One common reason for this failure is missing required libraries
Please fix the underlying issue and retry."

En la documentación de la instalación menciona que si usas una versión de 64 bits te hacen falta determinadas librerías. Sin embargo yo tengo lubuntu de 32 bits. Hago la comprobación con el comando uname -a que devuelve:

Linux user-Dell 4.13.0-37-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 7 14:12:29 UTC 2018 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Trato no obstante de instalar las librerías:

sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6

Y devuelve, también al añadir :i386 a los paquetes:

E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete lib32z1
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete lib32ncurses5
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete lib32bz2-1.0
E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete usando «*» con «lib32bz2-1.0»
E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete con la expresión regular «lib32bz2-1.0»
E: No se ha podido localizar el paquete lib32stdc++6
E: No se pudo encontrar ningún paquete con la expresión regular «lib32stdc++6»

¿Cuál puede ser el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

Cancelo el error y se abre el programa.

Da error con la ruta del jdk.

Pensaba que esa no era la solución, pero como en otras preguntas similares voy a Project Settings.

Localizo mi jdk con el comando

sudo update-alternatives --config java

Existen 2 opciones para la alternativa java (que provee /usr/bin/java).

0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java         1081
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java   1081
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java         1081

y en project settings se sustituye el path por defecto del jdk por:

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

De esta manera funciona la sincronización del graddle y funciona, por lo que creo que el problema está resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

instalacion de JDK

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

instalacion de ADB y FASTBOOT

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb adb android-tools-fastboot fastboot
```

librerías necesarias para android studio

```
 sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 lib32z1 libbz2-1.0:i386
```